# Adding another tsconfig.json file to project confuses tsc when finding definitions

Tags: typescript

I have a file structure for an application using `typescript` that looks akin to this;

```
./
./tsconfig.json
      /typings   /* typescript d.ts from typings */
      /src
      /sites
            /wiki
                  /scripts
                        /typescript-file.ts
                        /typescript-file.ts
```

and that works fine. but I have a situation where I would like to add a new `tsconfig.json` to the `/wiki/` directory, to change the way it behaves in just that part of the project.

At first glance this seems fine, but whenever I try to run `tsc` on that directory, I get a notification that it cannot find the typescript definitions in the `/typings/` directory - which is a higher level.

is there anything I can do about this that doesn't require me to clone the typings directory into the lower-level folder?

## root level `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "pretty": true,
    "declaration": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
  ]
}
```

### higher level `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the tsconfig.json files you're using in each location?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I have updated the question as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple thoughts.

One, would you object to introducing a `files` property? I've got a tsconfig that has a files property like this:

```
"files": [
    "typings/tsd.d.ts",
    "src/main.ts",
    ...
]
```

Everything that src/main.ts imports is still compiled. You only really have to specify the entry points of the import graph, and this is working out well enough for me.

Another slightly more controversial option may be to introduce the typings directory into your wiki directory via a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) rather than manually copying it.